# Google AdWords Scripts Get Views

Tags: javascript, video, google-ads-api

Good day

I have a question about Scripts in Google AdWords.

I know you can't modify frequency cap in a video ad, but I want to check impressions and views. Impressions is in the Stats Object, but where I can find views?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the views with the VIDEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/video-performance-report